# How can I set these lines to the radio buttons in C# Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, radio-button

[image]

I've tried many ways to set these lines on radio buttons, including using scripts(-), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font to a different size for every single line.
And in the Text field from the radio button write a plain line "----" for example:

first line with font 12 and bold
second line with font 14 and bold
third line with font 16 and bold

Otherwise, I would suggest picture boxes and draw the lines in a graphic program and add a picture box to every radio button.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).